# Remove border of a tabcontrolbox in visual studio 2015

Tags: vb.net

is there any way to remove the border of a tab control box? I wonder if it is followed with codes to remove the border or change the color. Thank you

[image: Please see attached screen snip.]

Comment: No.  Forcing your theme preferences in a Winforms design is a mistake.  If the user wants a dark UI then they'll select the dark Windows theme, TabControl paints itself accordingly.  https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-enable-dark-mode-in-windows-10

Comment: Oh, thanks! I am searching on the web but there are no best answers to remove the borderlines. Since you told me that there are no ways, I don't need to waste time searching for anything on the internet.